# Should I use “so”, “such” or “such a” in this example?

Tags: determiners

> Teo has been in the US for only three years, but his teachers say he has learned to speak perfect English in _____ short time because he's so happy at school.

Firstly I use *"such"* following the structure that my textbook taught me: **such + adjective + uncountable/plural noun (+ that)**

I applied this structure since I thought *"time"* is an uncountable noun. However, apparently, the answer is *"such a"*.

Comment: *Time* also has countable meanings, like when it means "a particular span of time": https://www.englishgrammar.org/time-countable-uncountable-noun/

Answer (score 0):

Teo has been in the US for only three years, but his teachers say he has learned to speak perfect English in _____ short time because he's so happy at school.

**Q. Should I use “so”, “such” or “such a” in this example?**

**In answer to your question**, I am sure somewhere in your text book there will be a note something like this

ATTENTION 1:
**with  singular nouns, we need an article “a or an” before the “adjective” in a sentence.**

### Therefore "such" cannot be used without the following "a"

The following are the correct terminology however "a" appears in both sentences, albeit in a different places.

learned to speak perfect **English in *“such a”* short time because he's so happy at
school.**

learned to speak perfect **English in "so" short "a" time because he's so happy at school.**

Why has the location of the "a" changed? The answer is simply because the way we use **"so short**". **Short has been modified by "so"**;

In this sentence we are emphasising the amount of time **"so short**" = "**very, very short**"

---

This link might be useful [**Using such in English**](https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/using-such-in-english/)

**So + adjective**: We often use so when we mean ‘to such a great extent’. With this meaning, "so" is a degree adverb that modifies adjectives and other adverbs:

**a** determiner (NOT PARTICULAR); **used before some words that express a number or amount:**

**short** adjective (TIME): **being an amount of time that is less than average or usual**:

**time** noun (PERIOD) A2 [ S or U ]; **a particular period of time for which something has been happening**, or that is needed for something:

They stayed with us for a short time. = They stayed with us for a short period (of time)

All Ref CED [**Such**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/such?q=SUCH)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: However, I had a doubt, is that phrase ".... learned English in so short a time" grammatically correct? I don't see that type of structure while using "so" in my textbook. The only one I find for adjectives is:
so + adjective or adverb (+that) 

Or is it a colloquialism?